# Jquery fadeIn/fadeOut img change

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, fadein

I've been trying to fix this bug of mines for about 3 hours now, searched everything and everywhere and can't find an answer.

The #test is an img element. I want the element to first fadeout, then change it's image and then fadein. But when I click on it it changes the image WHILE fading out and then fades in with the already changed image. Whats the problem here? Maybe I should use the animate() function or stop() or something else? Really confused, javascript and jQuery is so very hard

```
    $("#test").click(function(){
    ASD = $("#test").attr('alt');
    $("#test").fadeOut(700);
    $("#test").attr('src', ASD);
    $("#test").fadeIn(700);
```

Comment: Have your closed your click handler `})`?

Comment: Forgot to mention that this wasn't the only thing I was trying to do. I was also trying to make the image slide upwards and disapear while at the same time another image would slide upwars from the bottom and replace the old one. Tryed using the show() and hide() functions with the jqueryUI.js. Then tryed the FadeIn(), FadeOut() but still no luck. P.S. Yes I did close it, sorry forgot to paste it

Comment: If you're trying to slide something up, I guess `slideUp()` would be a good first choice for functions to try out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the callback parameter for `.fadeOut()` which gets called when the animation ends:

```
  $("#test").click(function(){
    ASD = $("#test").attr('alt');
    $("#test").fadeOut(700, function() {
       $("#test").attr('src', ASD);
       $("#test").fadeIn(700);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the callback of fadeOut so as to wait until the first animation is finished before you replace the source and start the second animation:

```
$("#test").on('click', function(){
    var ASD = $(this).attr('alt');
    $(this).fadeOut(700, function() {
        $(this).attr('src', ASD).fadeIn(700);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the callback option in [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/). This ensures the other actions will only happen once fadeOut finishes:

```
$("#test").click(function(){
    ASD = $("#test").attr('alt');
    $("#test").fadeOut(700, function() {
        $("#test").attr('src', ASD);
        $("#test").fadeIn(700);
    });
});
```